# how to pass a Integer or double value with volley

Tags: android, get, android-volley

I want to send a numeric value to the server using the getParams method.The Server API needs Integer values. server Api required integer value but i send a String value.

my code is :

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, C.LOGIN_URL, response, errorListener) {

            protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("NCode", 123456);
                map.put("Password", "abc12345");
                return map;
            }
        };
        C.addToQueue(request);
```

I tried using String.valueOf but my server needs a numeric value.
my server op is windows and language is asp.net

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when I sent string and int as part of the body.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("NCode", 123456);
jsonObject.put("Password", "abc12345");

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, C.LOGIN_URL, jsonObject, response, errorListener){

//insert code here

};

C.add(request);
```